# How do I make a <label> stay on the same line as it's <form>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I haven't been able to figure out how to implement their tips into my styling. How can I get my label to be on the left of my input, on the same line? Also I'm just learning how to code so sorry for the inevitable sloppy-ness. This is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  ;
}

.rng_box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 460px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 2px #E5E5E5;
  border: solid 3px #DEDEDE;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="rng_box">
  <h1 class="title">Random Number Generator</h1>
  <div>
    <form id="minAndMax">
      <label for="min">Minimum:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="min" name="min" class="form-control" value="1">
      <label for="max">Maximum:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="max" name="max" class="form-control" value="10">
      <br>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="generateRN()">Generate &#x1F389;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ignoreFields()">Ignore Fields</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="rng_answer">0</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, wrap your label and input inside a div and use flex.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Check the code below:

```
.label-wrap{
  display:flex;
}

<div class='label-wrap'>
  <label for="min">Minimum:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="min" name="min" class="form-control" value="1">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The `<br>` is not necessary, and w3schools is a particularly awful reference.

Comment: i just told him how he can do it, didnt see br and btw, please add some good reference here, so he can learn instead of reading your useless replies all over the internet. : )

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that : )

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `.form-control` css class has a `display: block` property in the `_forms.scss` file.
Such a property automatically makes the component goes to a new line. You can use `display: inline-block !important` instead and you will see the `input` going on the same line as the `label`.
In addition to this, you have also `<br>` tags right next your `label` tag to be removed.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="RNG.css">
    <title>Random Number Generator</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Users/trippyrock/Desktop/ToolScape/favicon.png">
<style>
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;;
}
.rng_box {
    background-color: white;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 800px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 460px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 2px #E5E5E5;
    border: solid 3px #DEDEDE;
}
.title {
    text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
    width:180px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.btn {
    margin: 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "rng_box">
        <h1 class="title">Random Number Generator</h1>
        <div>
            <form id="minAndMax">
                    <label for="min">Minimum:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="min" name="min" class="form-control" value="1">
                    <br>
                    <label for="max">Maximum:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="max" name="max" class="form-control" value="10">
                    <br>
            <div class="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="generateRN()">Generate &#x1F389;</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ignoreFields()">Ignore Fields</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr> 
            <h1 id="rng_answer">0</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="RNG.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that telling a new coder to use a bad practice like `!important` is the way to go...

Comment: Yes you are right, but on the other hand I cannot rewrite all the code... I just take his basis code and modifyed it in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap. you can use the bootstrap forms with other utility classess.

```
<div class="shadow-sm w-75 mx-auto mt-4 p-3 rounded-lg mw-75 text-center">
    <h1>Random Number generator</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="minAndMax">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Minimum:</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="number" id="min" name="min" class="form-control" value="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Maximum:</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="number" id="max" name="max" class="form-control" value="10" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" onclick="">Generate &#x1f389</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="">Ignore Fields</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```